# Determine if point is in rectangle, regardless of point order

Tags: python, rectangles

I am trying to understand how I can make this code verify whether the given point is in the specified rectangle. I want to to work both ways so that it does not matter what in order the corners of the triangle are inputted.

```
def isIn(fc, sc, p):
    if (p[0] >= fc and p[0] <= sc and p[1] >= fc[1] and p[1] <= sc):
        return True
    elif (p[0] <= fc and p[0] >= sc and p[1] <= fc[1] and p[1] >= sc):
        return True
    else :
      return False
fc = (3, 4)
sc = (1, 2)
p = (1.5, 3.2)
print(solve(fc, sc, p))
```

Comment: what is fc? what is sc?

Comment: I think it is first an second corner

Comment: Yes, they are first and second corners

Answer (score 0):

you can create new corner values by taking the min and the max of your current corner values, you will then have the bottom left and the up right corners:

```
def isIn(fc, sc, p):
    blc = (min(fc[0], sc[0]), min(fc[1], sc[1]))
    trc = (max(fc[0], sc[0]), max(fc[1], sc[1]))
    if (blc[0] <= p[0] <= trc[0] and blc[1] <= p[1] <= trc[1]):
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if the point x-coordinate is between the x-coordinates of the two corners, and the point y-coordinate is between the y-coordinates of the two corners.

```
if (fc[0] <= p[0] <= sc[0] or sc[0] <= p[0] <= fc[0]) and (fc[1] <= p[1] <= sc[1] or sc[1] <= p[1] <= fc[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...the corners of the triangle are inputted.

Which triangle? But not regarding that I'd say you shouldn't have corners in your rectangle but rather two tuples that are `(x1, x2)` and `(y1, y2)`. If you have that, assuming `p[0] = x, p[1] = y` you can have following if-statement:

```
def isIn(x_values, y_values, p):
    if (p[0] >= x_values[0] and p[0] <= x_values[1] and p[1] >= y_values[0] and p[1] <= y_values[1]):
        return True
    else :
      return False
x_values = (1, 3)
y_values= (2, 4)
p = (1.5, 3.2)
print(isIn(x_values, y_values, p))
```